# Como criar instalador para sistema web offline PHP + MySql

Tags: php, mysql, aplicação-web, instalador, sistemas-distribuídos

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de ordem de serviço em PHP e MySql pra ser rodado offline. Só que eu queria distribuir esse sistema, mas não sei como empacotaria ele.

Como faço para criar, tipo um instalador desse meu sistema pra instalar em outras máquinas? Existe algum programa ou helper pra isso ?

Lembrando que eu não gostaria de expor os arquivos com código fonte.

Alguém já fez isso ?

Comment: `Zend Guard` encapsula seu código fonte e o protege. Lembrando que só por que é uma aplicação web, não necessariamente precisa estar a internet. Uma configuração bem feita do seu ambiente `localhost` dá conta disso. Outra coisa, disponibilizando seu código como se fosse de prateleira, também deve fornecer instruções, e com isso inclua em seu pacote o instalador de algum ambiente como LAMP, WAMP, XAMPP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se for para Windows, existe uma alternativa que é utilizar o [`ExeOutput for PHP`](https://www.exeoutput.com/register.php), ele é um software pago e tem o intuito de criar um `.exe` contendo um navegador interno, baseado no Trident (Internet Explorer) ou no Chromium (Google Chrome), *na última versão apenas o Chromium está disponível.*

O executável gerado pelo software possui um servidor interno que permite executar o PHP 5.4 até o PHP 7.1, na última versão beta.

Ele possui o SQLite, uma vez que MySQL está sob licença GPL e uma [licença comercial é paga](https://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/).

Nenhum software é aprova de engenharia reversa, embora seja possível dificultar, nada é garantido. O [`ExeOutput for PHP`](https://www.exeoutput.com/register.php) possui alguns recursos de segurança e o principal é que o PHP não ficará exposto como `funcao.php` numa pasta, ele é "compilado", *não sei se é a palavra certa*, junto ao `.exe` e somente é necessário o `.exe` para executar o programa.

Entretanto ele tem desvantagens, além de ser pago, ele não permite que o usuário acesse o mesmo conteúdo em seu navegador, apenas poderá acessar através do navegador interno do `.exe`.

Essa é uma opção e talvez seja a menos pior solução para esta situação.

---

> *Eu participei das fases betas do ExeOutput for PHP, mas não possuo nenhum vinculo direto com a empresa. Essa é apenas uma alternativa que pode ser utilizada, se acreditar que seja a melhor.*

---

Não possuo informações sobre outros softwares que podem executar a mesma função, somente o `ZZEE PHPExe` mas está extremamente obsoleto, na versão PHP 5.2, e o `Bambalam` que também foi abandonado no PHP 4. Entretanto pode dar uma olhada [nesta publicação do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) que possui outras opções.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse campo aconselho utilizar o Wamp,por ele você tem acesso nesse formato.

Veja esse link:
http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Com ele você emula um servidor web,e pode instalar na maquina dos clientes para utilizarem sua aplicação,e se tiverem um servidor mais robusto você pode instalar e liberar acesso em rede.